# How to get Quote Order data in success cms page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have to show Quote Order data in success page after checkout in table as clients requirement. This include product, all prices, taxes and discounts in table as shown in checkout last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This I have done with getting customer id from the session and then taken out the last order id from the current customer in customer logged in case. And in guest case, I used the email saved in session and then taken out the order data for that customer.